# What is the mysterious Data Class in Ruby?

Tags: ruby

Today, I accidentally discovered the mysterious Data class in Ruby, and I can't find any useful information upon what it does, or why it's there. I assume it's part of the language implementation itself.

Does anybody know what it does?

```
mbp-scott:~ scott$ irb
ruby-1.9.3-p0 :001 > Data
=> Data
ruby-1.9.3-p0 :002 > Data.is_a? Module
=> true
ruby-1.9.3-p0 :003 > Data.is_a? Class
=> true
ruby-1.9.3-p0 :004 > Data.ancestors
=> [Data, Object, Kernel, BasicObject]
ruby-1.9.3-p0 :005 > Data.methods
=> [:allocate, :new, :superclass, :freeze, :===, :==, :<=>, :<, :<=, :>,
:>=, :to_s,:included_modules, :include?, :name, :ancestors, :instance_methods,
:public_instance_methods, :protected_instance_methods, :private_instance_methods,
:constants, :const_get, :const_set, :const_defined?, :const_missing, :class_variables,
:remove_class_variable, :class_variable_get, :class_variable_set,
:class_variable_defined?, :public_constant, :private_constant, :module_exec,
:class_exec, :module_eval, :class_eval, :method_defined?, :public_method_defined?,
:private_method_defined?, :protected_method_defined?, :public_class_method
:private_class_method, :autoload, :autoload?, :instance_method, :public_instance_method,
:nil?, :=~, :!~, :eql?, :hash, :class, :singleton_class, :clone, :dup, :initialize_dup,
:initialize_clone, :taint, :tainted?, :untaint, :untrust, :untrusted?, :trust, :frozen?,
:inspect, :methods, :singleton_methods, :protected_methods, :private_methods,
:public_methods, :instance_variables, :instance_variable_get, :instance_variable_set,
:instance_variable_defined?, :instance_of?, :kind_of?, :is_a?, :tap, :send,
:public_send, :respond_to?, :respond_to_missing?, :extend, :display, :method,
:public_method, :define_singleton_method, :object_id, :to_enum, :enum_for, :equal?,
:!, :!=, :instance_eval, :instance_exec, :__send__, :__id__]
ruby-1.9.3-p0 :006 > Data.instance_variables
=> []
ruby-1.9.3-p0 :007 > self
=> main
```

Comment: Not really an answer but: It's an undocumented part of the language so you can't really rely on it. I found an issue  that is currently assigned to Matz: http://redmine.ruby-lang.org/issues/3072

Comment: Weird. You'd think that it would be hidden inside something like `__Data`, if that's the case. I was messing around with modules in IRB when I crashed into this class - I got some really confusing errors.

Comment: @buddhabrot: +1 relying on it is one thing but clobbering it is another - the name "Data" seems like a pretty common one that a programmer might want to use.  It looks like defining your own "Data" class could cause unexpected behavior in the interpreter?  Yikes!

Comment: Yep, that chance is very likely. Don't diss Ruby too much for it..

Comment: If @buddhabrot had put his link down in an answer, I would have marked that as the answer since it contains a proper explanation... But in the end I had to choose, so I chose Tass, since he was also pointing me in the right direction.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Might be connected to [the C data type RUBY_T_DATA](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/trunk/include/ruby/ruby.h#L393). Which might be a way to store C data via the C API in the Ruby VM.

Comment: Yes, that does sound plausible.

Comment: On further investigation, it does seem to be an implementation detail relating to T_DATA that is exposed. @buddhabrot's comment link back up your suggestion.

Answer (score 4):

A few information from C-API documentation:

It is defined on [`object.c`](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/trunk/object.c#L2862-L2863). `marshal.c` uses it as a temporary internal container type [here](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/trunk/marshal.c#L918), [here](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/trunk/marshal.c#L1777) and [here](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/trunk/marshal.c#L1934). [`stringio.c`](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/trunk/ext/stringio/stringio.c#L1416) uses as the superclass of `StringIO`. [`error.c`](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/trunk/error.c#L1640) uses as the superclass of `NameError::message` (appears to be inaccessible from ruby side as doesn't start with a capital letter). Is superclass of `Iconv` in [`iconv.c`](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/trunk/ext/iconv/iconv.c#L1209).

It is implementation specific and should not be public. Just don't use it.

Comment: Not using it is definitely good advice, and I wouldn't dream of doing so. Unfortunately, I used it by accident when demonstrating an example code snippet in IRB to a co-worker!

Answer (score 2):

To be fair:

```
(main)> Class.is_a? Module
=> true
```

For what I can see you cannot make an instance of it so you wouldn't use it as a clean room (which I thought at first)

Here's more from object.c where the docs says it's defined. Seems it shares the same origin as TrueClass and NilClass (to name only those)

```
rb_define_class("Data", rb_cObject)
rb_undef_alloc_func(rb_cData);

rb_define_class("TrueClass", rb_cObject)
rb_define_class("NilClass", rb_cObject)
```

Whatever the purpose of that class, it has no methods of it's own and you cannot make an instance of it. Personally I would put my money on useless for now, maybe there are plans for this class in the future and so the const name Data is reserved.

Edit: There is more... Searching for rb_cData in the codebase turned up examples of it's use.

```
require 'stringio'
StringIO.ancestors
=> [StringIO, Enumerable, Data, Object, PP::ObjectMixin, Kernel, BasicObject]
```

It also appears in curses, socket, tk, iconv and in win32ole. Mostly used internally with Data_Wrap_Struct and for defining a base class.